# does using free() on a block always drop the mappings between its virtual memory and physical memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, c, virtual-memory

Let's say we want to allocate a block from the heap by using `malloc`. When allocating a a large size of memory, `malloc` calls `mmap` internally and for a small size allocation, `malloc` calls `brk` internally.

**Note that the heap is continuous when use `sbrk()` or `brk()`**

Let say my allocation is relative medium size and `malloc` calls `brk` internally.

let's say I call `malloc(small); malloc(medium); free(medium)`

according to this article [The history of Unix's confusing set of low-level ways to allocate memory](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/unix/SbrkVersusMmap)

> If you free()d the right things to create a block of unused space at the top of the break, malloc() and company might eventually call `brk()` or `sbrk()` to shrink the program's break and give the memory back to the OS.

since the free medium block is the last one(the small allocated block is the second last one),  so the memory will be given back to OS.

Below is my questions:

1. My understanding about the statement "the memory will be given back to OS" is:
   the free block's mappings between virtual memory and physical memory are dropped, other processes can use the physical memory that was originally occupied by this free block. Is my understanding correct?
2. this time I call `malloc(medium); malloc(small); free(medium)`
   Since there is still an allocated block in the end, does the free block's mapping between virtual memory and physical memory still exist? can other processes use this free block's physical memory?

Answer (score 1):

1. There are other mechanisms by which physical memory can be re-used for other purposes, swap in particular in this case — if memory pressure is high enough, a process’s physical memory can be swapped out to make room for something else.

   Nowadays, the main benefit of giving memory back to the operating system is that the operating system then *knows* that the memory won’t be used again, and therefore it can discard corresponding physical memory without any further ceremony. (See [my answer to the related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64042306/4500798) for details.)
2. Mappings between virtual memory and physical memory are somewhat fluid; see the above point about swap. In your scenario, the virtual address space allocated to the process can’t change, because the program break can’t be reduced, and the kernel has to assume that any physical memory mapped to it is “precious” and contains important data. But that doesn’t mean that the kernel can’t re-purpose the physical memory; it only means that it has to ensure, in doing so, that the data stored there isn’t lost.